# Implementing grabbing multiple items in sortable function (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I don't know why this sortable function cannot give me desired result, which is grabbing and dropping selected multiple elements in my sortable list.

My code looks like this:

```
setUsersList() {
  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
  });

    $('.users-list').sortable({
        items: "li:not(.to-resize)",
        connectWith: '.users-list',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        helper: function (e, item) {
            var elements = item.parent().children('.selected:not(.to-resize)').clone(); //there are other elements in between which I don't want to select, that's why I'm using 'not' selector, elements gives the proper and desired output of all selected items
            item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
            var helper = $('<li/>');
            return helper.append(elements);
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');
            ui.item.after(elements);
  }
    });
    $('.users-list').disableSelection();
}
```

When I'm dropping multiple selected items I'm copying one of them (f.ex. the first one is removed as expected, the second one is copied).How can I fix it?

Comment: could you share the whole html js code to reproduce the sample !

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some Syntax errors in your code. This might be due to it only being a partial example.

You can add the data to your helper, or you can simply hide the items in movement and then move them to a new position upon `stop`. Here is an example of latter:

```js
$(function() {

  function setUsersList() {
    $('ul.sortable').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
      if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected")
          .siblings().removeClass('selected');
      }
    });

    $('.users-list').sortable({
      items: "> li:not(.to-resize)",
      connectWith: '.users-list',
      helper: function(e, item) {
        var list = item.parent();
        var elements = $('.selected:not(.to-resize)', list);
        if (elements.length === 0) {
          return item;
        }
        elements.addClass("move-hide");
        var helper = $('<li>', {
          class: "ui-state-default",
          style: "width: 178px"
        });
        helper.text(elements.length + " Users");
        return helper;
      },
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        var list = $(this);
        var elements = $(".move-hide", list);
        elements.each(function(ind, el) {
          ui.item.before($(el));
        });
        $(".move-hide", list).removeClass("move-hide selected");
      }
    });
    $('.users-list').disableSelection();
  }
  setUsersList();
});
```

```css
.sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

.sortable li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.sortable li.selected {
  border-color: red;
}

.sortable li.move-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="users-list-1" class="sortable users-list">
  <li class="ui-state-default">User 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">User 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">User 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">User 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">User 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">User 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">User 7</li>
</ul>
```

There are still some logic issues, like if the user clicks to drag a single items, this creates a `mousedown`, `drag`, `drop`, `mouseup` series of events. What happens is that the Sort completes for a single list item and then the click is triggered on that item.

You also have no way to deselect items. You may consider adding that.

Hope that helps.